# Passing json string as an input to one of the parameters of a POST request body

Tags: json, jmeter

I need to pass a json string as a value to one parameter of a POST request body. My request body looks like this:

```
"parameter1":"abc",
"parameter2":"def",
"parameter3": "{\"id\":\"\",\"key1\":\"test123\",\"prod1\":{\"id\":\"\",\"key3\":\"test123\",\"key4\":\"12334\",\"key5\":\"3\",\"key6\":\"234334\"},\"prod2\":{\"id\":\"\",\"key7\":\"test234\",\"key8\":1,\"key9\":true}}\"",
"parameter4":false,
"parameter5":"ghi"
}
```

For parameter3 I need to be pass a string value in json format. The json file is located in my local system and is a huge file, so it would make sense if I can pass it as a jmeter variable. I tried as below:

```
{
"parameter1":"abc",
"parameter2":"def",
"parameter3": "${jsonObj}",
"parameter4":false,
"parameter5":"ghi"
}
```

after adding a JSR223 preprocessor with the code below:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

String fileContents = new File("path to json//myJson.json").getText('UTF-8');
vars.put("fileContents",fileContents);

var deltaJson = vars.get("fileContents");
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(deltaJson);
vars.put("jsonObj", JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

But I get below error:

```
exceptions":{"exceptionType":"System.JSONException","exceptionMessage":"Unexpected character ('$' (code 36)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]"}
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way of doing this, JMeter comes with [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) so you can achieve the same much faster and without having to do any scripting

Something like:

```
{
  "parameter1": "abc",
  "parameter2": "def",
  "parameter3": ${__FileToString(path to json//myJson.json,UTF-8,jsonObj)},
  "parameter4": false,
  "parameter5": "ghi"
}
```

Also be aware of the following facts:

- the recommended language for using in JSR223 Test Elements is [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) as it provides the maximum performance
- you seem to be using [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object which cannot be used outside of the browser context therefore your code fails to generate proper JSON hence your request fails as you're passing `${jsonObj}` as it is, the substitution doesn't happen, you can look to [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file yourself and see the exact reason of your script failure

Comment: Tried using __FileToString() function but getting error - [{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: id at [line:4, column:21]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]

Comment: It was an error on my part while using __FileToString() function. The json file had to be passed with Escape characters ('\'). It worked. Thanks @Dmitri T